# How to create dynamic Splash Screen in Android Studio using Shared Preferences to set TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to get my Android app's initial screen to update a TextView whenever a SharedPreference is changed in the settings menu, but I'm not sure exactly where to go from here.

This is a method that I added to my initial screen code to see if it would change when the preference was changed in the settings, but it never gets called according to my debugging efforts. Other parts of our application (mainly the search function) call this successfully.

```
public class initialScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_initial_screen);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key){
    String nameOfPref = "test";
    if (key.equals("instance")){
        nameOfPref = sharedPreferences.getString("instance","test");
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    tv.setText(nameOfPref);
  }

 // ... plus some other StartActivity(intent) methods that don't matter here
}
```

Which the preference is set by a different class like this:

```
public class mySettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
  @Override
  public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
  }
}
```

I guess I'm trying to figure out how to make my initial screen dynamic and 'always listening' for that preference to change.

Comment: How would the initial screen get updated though? If the settings comes after, or do you go back to your initial screen at some point?

Comment: The aim is to have a TextView acting as a title be updated to be named after whatever SharedPreference is selected in the settings menu. The user is given the initalScreen to start, with a default setting, then can go to the settings and change to a different 'version' of the app (changed with the sharedPreference), and the title is updated to reflect what 'version' the user is in

Comment: In that case in the oncreate read the preferences and tie the output to your text box.